# Can WebHDFS UI delete functionality be disabled?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ambari, webhdfs

Starting from HDP 3.0, the WebHDFS UI (i.e. the namenode UI file explorer on port 50070) now includes a bin icon that can be used to delete HDFS files. It seems to do this by calling a rest api DELETE hook, but in doing so it also seems to bypass any file or folder permissions.
In other words, anyone who can reach the UI on 50070 is now able to delete any HDFS file.

Is there a way I can keep the WebHDFS UI accessible for cluster users, but prevent them from being to delete files?

Possible ideas may be somehow disable or block the DELETE hook, making the whole WebHDFS read-only or implementing some form of authentication, while keeping the UI accessible. What does the community recommend for this?

Comment: The webUI is not secure by default, anyway. Youd need to enable Kerberos + SPNEGO / use Knox to fully protect that endpoint

Comment: There are several reasons why someone wouldn't want Kerberos:
1. Learning curve (kdc, keytabs all aren't managed through the GUI)
2. Kerberos authentication impacts every user.
3. WebHDFS, Yarn, Oozie UI's are all completely blocked by Kerberos and not trivial to allow again, as you'll have to start digging into how the browser authenticates itself.
4. Even when overcoming all the above, you'd still end up with the problem of how to manage hdfs 'delete' rights once the user is logged in. Kerberos after all only does a pass/fail check.

Comment: Sure, that's all valid, but without it, the cluster nor endpoints are secure, and every other action that relies on a username is passed as a literal string. E.g. You can forge [a url parameter on webhdfs to impersonate any valid user](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#HDFS_Configuration_Options)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any previous solutions for this, so I experimented for myself and came up with the following. Sharing for other people's benefit:

```
Custom core-site: 
hadoop.http.staticuser.user = browser
hadoop.user.group.static.mapping.overrides = browser=;
```

What this does is change the webHDFS user to a non-existing hdfs user 'browser' (By default it seems to get supergroup user privileges).

The second property overwrites what groups the specified user gets assigned to. In this case, I overwrite the user 'browser' to not belong to any group, thus removing its supergroup privileges.

Afterwards when you check the webHDFS UI you'll still see the bin icon next to files, but if the icon is clicked the page will display a permissions error.